# Java Class - Do not wait for process to exit

Tags: java, process

I have created a process like so to launch the android emulator:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("emulator.exe -avd Testing -no-boot-anim -scale 0.42");
```

My Java class does what it needs to do but it never ends since that Process has not been destroyed. I just want my Java class to do what it needs to do and exit without waiting for or destroying the started process. I've tried:

`System.Exit(0)`

But my Java class doesn't get pass it. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to processes the child process' stdout (and stderr) otherwise the call to exec method is blocking. See here [Why does Process.waitFor() never return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967932/why-does-process-waitfor-never-return)