# Process is hanging in java, waitFor() takes forever even though I've read (Input/Error)Stream

Tags: java, process, stream

I'm having trouble running multiple Processes in Java.

I have a loop which runs Processes from a vector `cmds`, it currently runs the first process and then the second hangs.

```
   ProcessBuilder proc = null;
   for (String cmd:cmds){
       proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split("\\s"));
       Process p = proc.start();

       //Handle streams

       //in
       Scanner stdin = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
       while(stdin.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(stdin.nextLine());
       }
       //err
       Scanner stderr = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());
       while(stderr.hasNextLine()){
             System.out.println(stderr.nextLine());
       }
       //wait
       p.waitFor();
   }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967947/1984350) clearly doesn't work for me as I have read from the InputStream and ErrorStream of each process. What am I misunderstanding?

How can I fix this?

Note: I removed the try block which I have since it's not really help in this sample code

**EDIT**

```
 proc = new ProcessBuilder(cur_string.split("\\s"));
 proc. redirectErrorStream(true);
 final Process p = proc.start();//Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cur_string);
 //Handle streams
 //in
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
                Scanner stdin = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
                while(stdin.hasNextLine()){
                            System.out.println(stdin.nextLine());
                }
                stdin.close();
                }
        }).start();

  //wait
  p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Do any of your commands require input? Also, you might want to combine combine your standard error and output streams with `proc. redirectErrorStream(true)`, and use a separate thread to process the output stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You have to close the process's input stream.
2. You can't assume that all the standard output will be written before any of the standard error. You either have to merge those streams prior to exec() or else read one of them in a separate thread.

Comment: I did what you said, it's still not working. See @Edit in my original question, please help.

Comment: Oh sorry abt that, It works! Thanks! It froze because the second command was `grep x` and was hanging 'coz it was waiting for input (I guess).