# Running batch command gets stuck on Runtime.exec.waitFor()

Tags: java, runtime.exec, thread-sleep

I run a batch command from Java like this:

```
String command ="cmd /c " + mPathToZip + " a -tzip " + source
            + "foo.zip " + source + "* && exit";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So basically I need it to run the command and wait until it's finished before I do something else.

The problem is the JVM gets stuck at the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();

I already tried this when unzipping something and works fine, but now when I zip something it gets stuck. Also, I've tried the command manualy and it works.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to threads.

Comment: So, yo are running this, the ZIP is being created, but the waitFor() never returns?

Comment: @CodeChimp Yes. The zip is created on my hdd but the waitFor never returns.

Comment: Could be the classic full buffer blocking issue. I would suggest you read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) and then use [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec//tutorial.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967932/why-does-process-waitfor-never-return

Comment: Tried it again with the solution provided there but the output is the same :(